# How can I trigger the js function without using onchange or onclick or any solution for this

Tags: javascript, php, dropdown, html-select

I am trying to retrieve data from a database to Select/Option tags using PHP. Then once someone submits the form, it will update the database, and then it will print onto a letter. Here the data to the option will be retrieved automatically from the database, but the user can also change it to another given option.

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" style="padding-top: 5px;">Job Category</label>
        <select name="j_cate" id='job_cate' class="form-control" onchange="changeFunc()" >
            <option> </option>
            <?PHP foreach ($j_categories as $j_category) { ?>

            <option value="<?PHP echo $j_category->id; ?>" > <?PHP echo $j_category->jobCat; ?> </option>

            <?php } ?>
        </select>
        <input type="hidden" value="check" id="my_hidden_field" name="my_hidden_field" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here comes the main question.
I want to get the text inside the options as in the main table it has numbers like (1, 2, 3) and the main table linked to another table that has relevant names to those numbers. I have echoed the names as "jobCat" and ids as "id". I want to get only the text part.

For that, I used JS query

```
<script>
function changeFunc() {

    var selectedValue = $("#job_cate").children("option").filter(":selected").text()

    document.getElementById('my_hidden_field').value = selectedValue;
}
```

Now the problem solved. **But only when the user clicks and selects any options from the dropdown. Otherwise, the program will not work.**

I want the program to retrieve the text to **my_hidden_id** even when the user doesn't click and the program automatically selects an option.

Comment: It seems to me you're approaching the problem on the wrong side. If your values are IDs, that means you can retrieve the names from the database when the form is submitted, so there is no real reason to try and submit the name alongside the ID within the form. Doing another query isn't that costly. However, if you insist on having the name in the form, then I suggest modifying the value of your options to contain both the ID and the name in a delimited form (for example, `value="123;name_of_category"`), which you can then just explode in PHP.

Comment: By the way, the answer to the question from the title would be to simply call the function when the page loads.

Comment: @El_Vanja The thing is when refresh there are no selected jobs in the form. When the user selects an employeeID (which is another input that I haven't included thinking it will be irrelevant) automatically the options will get id and the name. If the user clicks and updates the option, there is no problem. But if he didn't click it, there is an error coming.

Comment: You can fix that issue by doing any of the three things I have listed in my previous comments.

Comment: @El_Vanja can you put that value(value="123;name_of_category") as an answer or as a comment. I think I might be able to change the code as you said. But I don't know how to differ the value and the name from it.

Comment: You just take the form value in PHP and [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode) it. You're the one who decides what the string should look like, so you will know what the first part is and what the second part is after exploding. If you generate it like `id;name`, then you know that the first index of the exploded array is the id and the second index is the name.

Comment: Thank you so much @El_Vanja I will try it. :D :D